# Why is mongoDB a database server?

Tags: database, mongodb, server, nosql, paradigms

I've recently begun learning mongoDB and came across the phrase "mongoDb is a database server."
There was no explanation, and I'm a little confused because servers simply host resources and have an IP address assigned to them.

Pretty sure that I am confused because I don't know enough of anything.

But in summary can someone explain what is meant by "mongoDB is a database server".

I would greatly appreciate it. I've been looking all morning and haven't found a "suitable" answer

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

The term "server" is ambiguous.

On one hand a "server" can be a (typically big) computer, which runs some software. Typical examples are database or web server. See [Server computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing))

On the other hand a "server" can be a software. Usually this software does not do anything, until a client software connects to it and ask for some activities. Typical example is a web-server and a browser as client. Server and client software can run on the same computer, this is no problem at all. See [Client–server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

For better distinction some people use "server" for computer hardware and "service" for the software item. But in general these term are not used consistently and mixed with each other.